# Ruby 'Range.last' does not give the last value. Why?

Tags: ruby, range

When using the triple dot notation in a ruby Range object, I get this:

```
(0...5).each{|n| p n}
0
1
2
3
4
```

When I use the 'last' method I get:

```
(0...5).last
 => 5
```

I would have expected 4

Is this is a bug? Or is there something I don't understand about the the concept of a Range object?

Comment: Here's what you're not understand about Range objects: consider the range `Math::E...Math::PI`. What should `last` be? Ranges are literally just a start, an end, and whether or not the end is excluded. The fact that integer ranges can be enumerated over is a special feature. Ranges have lots of other uses.

Comment: Range has the `end` method for that, I pressumed. I'm missing the `start` method though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is by design. The Ruby 2.0 documentation is [more specific](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Range.html#method-i-last):

> Note that with no arguments `last` will return the object that defines the end of the range even if `exclude_end?` is `true`.
>
> ```
> (10..20).last      #=> 20
> (10...20).last     #=> 20
> (10..20).last(3)   #=> [18, 19, 20]
> (10...20).last(3)  #=> [17, 18, 19]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

As Stefan has answered your observed behavior is expected and documented.

If you want to obtain the last element which would be enumerated by the range without having to enumerate the whole range, you could use [`Enumerable#reverse_each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reverse_each)

```
irb> (0...5).reverse_each.first
=> 4
```

Comment: `reverse_each.first` *does* enumerate the whole range

Comment: Or maybe `(0...5).max`

Comment: @Stefan You're totally right.  Don't know what I was thinking -- how could Enumerable have special knowledge of reverse enumeration of the class it's mixed into.

Comment: `(1...100000000).reverse_each.first` will consume a huge amount of memory, but `(1...100000000).max.to_i` won't... Don't forget to use `to_i` because ranges like `(4..3).max` will return nil.