# Why is (10..20).last the same as (10...20).last

Tags: ruby

Why are these two equivalent?

```
(10..20).last     #=> 20
(10...20).last    #=> 20
```

This sounds like a duplicate of [Ruby 'Range.last' does not give the last value. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467846/ruby-range-last-does-not-give-the-last-value-why), but the answers to that question simply say it's by design. Why is it designed like that? What is the purpose of `..` and `...` returning the same values for `last` when everything else is different?

Comment: Alright, the answer to that simply states, this is by design. So my question then and I'll update this above, WHY is this by design? Why is this inconsistent?

Comment: It is not inconsistent. last return the last object in the range. In both case the start of the range is 10 and the last is 20.

What you really want is (10...20).max #=> 19

.last and .last(count) are different methods and behave differently.

Comment: Don't think of (1..3) as creating a set of numbers from 1 to 3, think of it as creating a Range object starting at 1, and ending at 3 with inclusive behavior.  Then (1...3) is the same object with exclusive behavior at the end.  Both have the same last value, just different behavior.

Comment: @NickVeys sure, I get it, they're both in Range class and the call to the method last differs to both. I get that the creators intended for last to be the same. I just want to understand why it was designed this way since it's counterintuitive. What's the purpose of .. and ... having the same last values?

Comment: #last is just a method. It's up to the Range object (or its descendants) how to implement it.

Comment: `(10..20).last(3)` is `[18, 19, 20]` for me. I think that's a bug in your code or your Ruby version.

Comment: @K- I'm not arguing it's a great method for the class. :)  I especially think the behavior changes between `#last()` and `#last(n)` make it especially confusing for exclusive ranges.

Comment: @Max that's not even relevant to my question. I've deleted it. Must have been modified in one of the admin mods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll answer your question with a question: what is the last value of `0.0...1.0`?

In general, [not every Range is enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html#method-i-each). For such ranges with an excluded end, there really is no meaningful `last` value *other* than the value used to define the end of the range.

Note also that you can enumerate **inclusive** ranges where `last` *is not the last value enumerated!*

```
(0..3.2).to_a.last
# 3
(0..3.2).last
# 3.2
(0..Float::INFINITY).to_a.last
# don't wait up for this one
```

The motivation of the design is that "the value used to define the end of a range" is not identical to "the last value enumerated by a range". `last` gives you the former.